# Button in table row redirect to another page with the data of the row in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, button

I would like to insert a button in every row of a table and when I click on this button, it redirect me to another page with the data of the single table row using Laravel
How can I do this?

This is my form:

```
<html>
        <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">USERNAME</th>
          <th scope="col">MAC ADDRESS</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach ($data as $item)
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{$item->id}}</th>
          <td>{{$item->username}}</td>
          <td>{{$item->mac_addr}}</td>
          <td>
          <form action="{{url('singleDevice')}}" method="get">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Select</button>
          </form>
        </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
      
    </html>
```

This is my controller:

```
class DeviceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data=Device::all();
        return view('device', compact("data"));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('registrationDevice');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = new Device;
        //On left field name in DB and on right field name in Form/view
        $input -> username = $request->username;
        $input -> mac_addr = $request->mac_address;
        $input->save();

        return redirect('registrationDevice')->with('message', 'DATA SAVED');
    }

    public function show(Device $device)
    {
        
        return view('singleDevice');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a form? use the link

```
<form action="{{url('singleDevice')}}" method="get">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Select</button>
</form>
```

replace with

```
<a href="{{ route('show', ['device' => $item->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
```

and configure the URL in the router as /singleDevice/{device}

```
Route::get('/singleDevice/{device}', [DeviceController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to insert my Route: 
Route::get('device', [DeviceController::class, 'index'])->name('devices');
Route::get('registrationDevice', [DeviceController::class, 'create'])->name('registration');
Route::post('store', [DeviceController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
Route::get('singleDevice/device', [DeviceController::class, 'show'])->name('show');

How should I modify the routes?

Comment: @Symon94 edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your form like :

```
<tbody>
   @foreach ($data as $item)
     <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$item->id}}</th>
       <td>{{$item->username}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->mac_addr}}</td>
       <td>
         <a href="{{ url('/singleDevice/'.$item->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
       </td>
     </tr>
   @endforeach
</tbody>
```

If you want to use **route name**, you can change by :

```
<td>
  <a href="{{ route('show', ['deviceID' => $item->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
</td>
```

Change your route like :

```
Route::get('/singleDevice/{deviceID}', [DeviceController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
```

Change your `show` function of the controller like:

```
public function show($deviceID)
 {
   $device = Device::firstWhere('id', $deviceID);
   return view('singleDevice', compact("device"));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this  as you have already used form in your code

```
<form action="{{ route('show',  $item->id) }}" method="get">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Select</button>
</form>

public function show(Device $device)
 { 
    return view('singleDevice');
 }
```

For Route you can pass `$device`:

```
Route::get('/singleDevice/{$device}', [DeviceController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
```